# Get specific page from URL and get the data with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
window.onload= function(){
    var page = window.location.hash;
    if(window.location.hash != ""){
        page = page.replace('#page:', '');
        getdata('src/'.page);
    }
}
```

After the window loads, i want the page to look in the URL, see if there is a # is set, and if so, i want to grab the page and display it inside a DIV. So for example, a link would be `<a href="page.php#page:contact.php">link</a>`. So when somenone clicks on the link, the page thinks and grabs the data from contact.php, and puts it inside the div. But now, this isn't working. No errors, no warnings, no nothing. Help please? Thanks!

Edit: Getdata:

```
function getdata(file){

    openloading(); // loading message

    $('#content').fadeOut('slow', function () { // Content is the div where all the content must be in
        $.get(file, function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
            $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
        })
    })

    updateusersonline();
}
```

And updateusersonline() directly too:

```
function updateusersonline(){
    $.get('src/usersonline.php', function(data3) {
        $('#usersonline').html(data3);
    })
```

Comment: What does your `getdata()` function look like?

Comment: `getdata('src/'.page);` should be `getdata('src/' + page);`

Comment: @Joey Ahh i see! Post an answer so i can accept it! I've realy been doing too much php lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getdata('src/'.page);` should be `getdata('src/' + page);`